# How to use Curiously Recurring Template Pattern for Bridge Pattern?

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, crtp, bridge

I have been researching the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern to determine how I could use it to implement a Bridge Design Pattern.

My problem is connecting, (wiring up), the IBridgeConnector::GetBridgeImpl method to the Bridge::GetBridgeImpl method since the overriding method is actually templated.

Since virtual dispatch won't work in this case, what is the best way to point these methods to each other?  Function Delegates?  Is there a better pattern for this?

How should this be done?

Thanks for the help!

Made the best code simplification I can without shared_ptrs everwhere and OpenGL and DirectX calls. :) Hopefully this will be useful to someone in the future!

```
#include <string>
/********************************************************************/
class BridgePart
{
public:
    BridgePart * OtherPart;
};

/********************************************************************/
// Connects a BridgeSource and a BridgeImplementation
class BridgeConnector
{
public:
    static BridgeConnector * implementor;

    // Need a way, (Function Delegates?) to point this method
    // This method will loop until stack overflow.
    template <typename ValueTemplateType>
    BridgePart * GetBridgeImpl(ValueTemplateType * source)
    {
        return implementor->GetBridgeImpl<ValueTemplateType>(source);
    }
};
BridgeConnector * BridgeConnector::implementor = nullptr;

/********************************************************************/
// Where the Magic is At, (CRTP)
template <typename BridgeImplementationTemplateType>
class Bridge : public BridgeConnector
{
public:
    template <typename ValueTemplateType>
    IBridgePart * GetBridgeImpl(IBridgePart * source)
    {
        // NOTE:  This method never gets called.
        // CRTP Magic Here to Semi-Specify Pure Virtual Methods
        return static_cast<BridgeImplementationTemplateType>(this)
            ->GetBridgeImpl( (ValueTemplateType) source);
    }
};

/********************************************************************/
class BridgeImplementation1 : 
    public Bridge<BridgeImplementation1>,
    public BridgePart
{
public:
    class CustomImpl : public BridgePart
    {
    public:
        template <typename SourceTemplateType>
        BridgePart(SourceTemplateType source){}
            /* Does proprietary stuff. */
    };

    template <typename ValueTemplateType>
    BridgePart * GetBridgeImpl(ValueTemplateType & source)
    {
        return new CustomImpl<ValueTemplateType>(source);       
    }
    // Constructor
    BridgeImplementation1()
    {
    }
};

/********************************************************************/
class BridgeSource1 : public BridgePart {};
class BridgeSource2 : public BridgePart {};
class Client
{
    BridgeSource1 source1;
    BridgeSource2 source2;
    BridgeConnector * connector;
    bool usingImpl1;

    Client()
    {
        usingImpl1 = true; // from config file.
        connector = new BridgeConnector();
        connector->implementor = usingImpl1 
            ? (BridgeConnector *) new BridgeImplementation1()
            : nullptr; // (BridgeConnector *) new BridgeImplementation2();  
        // removed to shorten code.
    }

    void Init()
    {
        source1.OtherPart = connector->GetBridgeImpl<BridgeSource1>(& source1);
        source2.OtherPart = connector->GetBridgeImpl<BridgeSource2>(& source2); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Use a debugger, and step through the code line by line (stepping into the functions called), and you will see quite quickly why you get the stack overflow. As a hint, you call `LoadDriver` with a pointer, and keep calling `LoadDriver` with a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a bit of a misunderstanding of CRTP. It is not a plug in replacement for virtual dispatch. In your case, IBridge has no virtual dispatch, so calling IBridge->LoadDriver will always give you the default base class implementation, regardless of the underlying derived class. If you want a generic interface, you need some kind of virtual dispatch. CRTP is just a way of avoiding virtual dispatch in cases where it is not necessary, for example when a base class member function calls in to other virtual functions.

If you want to avoid virtual dispatch completely in you case, you can not completely decouple the client from the Bridge, you would need to template Client on Bridge which doesn't really give you any advantage over just templating on Derived.

Here's a shot at doing what you want. It assumed that you pass some generic pointer through IBridge, which Bridge uses CRTP to interpret and pass down to BridgeImpl. Obviously, you've abandoned all hope of type safety on the arguments at this point.

```
class IBridge {
    virtual void LoadDriver(void *) = 0;
};

template <typename Impl>
class Bridge : public IBridge {
    void LoadDriver(void * v) override {
        static_cast<Impl*>(this)->LoadDriverImpl(*static_cast<Impl::arg_type *>(v));
    }
};

class BridgeImpl : public Bridge<BridgeImpl> {
    typedef std::string arg_type;
    void LoadDriverImpl(const std::string & s){ /*...*/ }
};
```

Comment: Okay, I think I now understand the relevance of virtual dispatch with this problem, IBridge::LoadDriver isn't being "overridden" by Bridge::LoadDriver ... The solution that I have been trying to avoid is using a static function pointer of some sort to link the two.  I am /really/ trying to avoid using RTTI and dynamic casts, which is why I am using CRTP in the first place.  What would you recommend? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't need RTTI/dynamic casts for virtual dispatch. From the example you gave, vanilla virtual dispatch i.e. Derived inherits from IBridge directly, which has a virtual LoadDriver, is probably the best solution. If there is more complexity in the member function calls, you might consider using CRTP at a lower level i.e. IBridge has a virtual LoadDriver, which Bridge overrides and calls a non-virtual LoadDriverImpl on the Derived classes using CRTP (This makes no sense on it's own, but maybe would in a more complex use case)

Comment: The entire context is that the Bridge API is in the Framework Tier, (library), consumed by an Application tier, (lib), consumed by a Client tier, (.exe)... The Client tier provides BridgeImplementation : public Bridge<BridgeImplementation>, public IBridgePart .. at run-time, the Application Tier calls a Framework Tier based Service Locator to go find the other end of the Bridge implemented in the Client Tier.  The Application and Framework Tiers know nothing about the implementations except that an IBridgePart::ICommandPattern will be returned by the BridgeServiceLocator. HTH

Comment: OK, I think everything I said still applies. Assuming your current design, make IBridge::LoadDriver virtual and fix the problems mentioned by Joachim - at the moment there is no way to know what type to use for ValueTemplateType in the Bridge. You probably need the IBridge LoadDriver to be templated, call via virtual dispatch into a Bridge::LoadDriverImpl function, which calls via CRTP into the actual implementation LoadDriverImpl function

Comment: Also your IBridge must know the full set of types it can take at compile time, unless you give it some other method of determining it at run time, at the moment you have no way to get from void * back to std::string when you are in IBridge::LoadDriver. Do you actually need a completely arbitrary type here??

Comment: Would you mind taking another look?  I updated it to reflect what is closer to my actual situation.  I hope the code is pretty enough.

Comment: You basically seem to be trying to use virtual template functions - i.e. mixing static and runtime polymorphism. Such a concept is not possible in c++ - it would require an unbounded number of entries in the vtable. I'd suggest restricting the types you pass through LoadDriver. Use a base class, or a finite number of virtual overloaded methods.

Comment: Yes, I want to mix static and runtime polymorphism! There!  I said it! :)  I feel smarter now.  *cough.  How do I do this?  Would delegates work?  Or some other recommendation?  How would you use delegates? P.S. Everything is possible in C++-- _asm{} !

Comment: 'Delegate' covers a multitude of different concepts in c++. You can't get away from the theoretical problem behind this though, you cannot use runtime polymorphism over an infinite number of types which is effectively what a virtual template would allow you to do. It is difficult to say what's best without knowing what these arguments you are passing around actually are, but my guess is that there is some natural abstraction of those arguments that is missing. If not i.e. you really need completely arbitrary types, something like boost::any is an option.

Comment: Well, to be more specific, the types I am passing around, bridge sources, are actually abstractions of GPU concepts, Shader, Buffer, Device, Context, DisplayDevice, etc... they all have specific implementation requirements if I am using either DirectX, or OpenGL, Linux, or Windows ... DirectX 9, 11, etc.  So, in actuality, 50-ish, with about 6 times that in bridge implementations.

Comment: So a single IBridge would, for example, take some kind of Shader, and each bridge implementation would take a specific implementation of a Shader? If that's the case I would probably have the various implementations inherit from a shader base and where possible have the bridge implementations (CustomImpls?) use that abstraction. If needs be you downcast, but this sort of defeats the point as the two  sides are tightly coupled. If you are trying to avoid the cost of virtual functions, you have to sacrifice that decoupling, at which point the Bridge becomes a bit pointless as far as I can see?

Comment: The implementations of Shader once derived from my Abstract Shader.  The thing is, during loading compiledshaders to memory, I had to do call virtual initialization methods on the derived implementations during object construction, (which is fun with constructor delegation).  It was a bit cludgey.  So now, the implementations take the Source class instances, and encapsulates them, rather than direct inheritance, so they can initialize, etc, as needed.

Comment: Is it the case that the underlying implementation on one side of the bridge is tied to one specific argument type i.e. specific Shader implementation or whatever? If so Bridge seems like the wrong pattern here?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `LoadDriver` in the `Client::Init` function, the `ValueTemplateType` template parameter is `std::string*`, i.e. a pointer. The bridge implementation classes `BridgeImplementation1` and `BridgeImplementation2` have functions which *doesn't* take a pointer. So when the compiler tries to find a matching `LoadDriver` function, it doesn't consider the functions taking a non-pointer argument, only the one taking the pointer argument.

You should change the `LoadDriver` functions in `BridgeImplementation1` and `BridgeImplementation2` to take a pointer argument.

Comment: I am not too sure I understand.  The interface, and the base Bridge class have to have the same signature to override, right?  Then Bridge does some Magical static_cast stuff so the same signature isn't required.  I don't think the Bridge::LoadDriver method is override the IBridge::LoadDriver ... Sorry, I think I understand the patterns good enough, just not the C++ syntax.

Comment: @WindAndFlame The `LoadDriver` function in `IBridge` takes a pointer, you can not use a pointer argument to call a function taking a non-pointer argument. Change the `LoadDriver` functions in the child classes to take a _pointer_ to `std::string` instead.

Comment: Joachim is right, the same problems are seen in C if not prototyped correctly

Comment: I changed the names of the Implemented methods to reduce ambiguity... Right now, I am trying to troubleshoot the connection between IBridge::LoadDriver(*) and Bridge::LoadDriver(*).  Will Virtual Dispatch not work because of the templates?  How do you solve this problem?

Comment: @WindAndFlame change `void ImplementedLoadDriver(std::string v)` argument to std::string *v

Comment: @Ulterior & others- The issue, so far isn't with the static_cast<>()->call() ...  It is with the virtual dispatch from IBridge::LoadDriver to Bridge::LoadDriver that isn't even happening, the program never gets to this static_cast<>.  I am trying to figure out the best way to simulate that the template class's method overrides the interface--perhaps using function delegates, pointers, or some other nifty design pattern that is better for this purpose.  Sorry for the ambiguity, will make another pass on the code.

Comment: Well the problem is both. The CRTP never gets hit because of the points mentioned in my answer. The code wouldn't work even if it did because of the problems in this answer.

Comment: Okay, could you look one more time and see if this particular problem has been addressed?  It was pseudo code originally, I hope this is a bit better.